# How can I make swig_add_library (cmake) process the provided files

Tags: cmake, swig

When using swig_add_library provided by the cmake "plugin" [UseSWIG.cmake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Modules/UseSWIG.cmake) as follows

```
swig_add_library (mylib LANGUAGE tcl SOURCES foo.ii)
```

foo.ii is silently ignored. If I rename foo.ii to foo.i and then

```
swig_add_library (mylib LANGUAGE tcl SOURCES foo.i)
```

foo.i is processed as expected. 
How would I need to write my CMakeLists.txt so that swig_add_library process the SOURCES provided as an argument to its call.

Comment: I guess, you speak about [`include(UseSWIG)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/UseSWIG.html) `FindSWIG)` it's just for the binary location

Comment: Why you don't want to use the .i suffix ?

Answer (score 1):

I think, the extension `.i` for swig file is hardcoded (i.e. mandatory) in UseSwig.cmake macro.

```
macro(SWIG_ADD_LIBRARY name)
... 
foreach(it ${_SAM_SOURCES})
    if(${it} MATCHES "\\.i$")
      set(swig_dot_i_sources ${swig_dot_i_sources} "${it}")
    ...
endforeach()
...
foreach(it ${swig_dot_i_sources})
  SWIG_ADD_SOURCE_TO_MODULE(${name} swig_generated_source ${it})
  set(swig_generated_sources ${swig_generated_sources} "${swig_generated_source}")
  list(APPEND swig_generated_targets "${swig_gen_target}")
endforeach()
```

src: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Modules/UseSWIG.cmake#L306

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18831489)

Comment: That was the goal of the first sentence -_-, maybe now it's more clear ?